# pandas group by week and get day

Tags: pandas, timestamp, pandas-groupby

supose i have tested data like below:

```
import pandas as pd

data_dic = {
    "day": ['2019-01-18', '2019-01-18', '2019-01-18', '2019-01-19',
            '2019-01-19','2019-01-25', '2019-02-19', '2019-02-24'],
    "data": [0, 1,3,3, 0, 1,2 ,5],
    "col2": [10, 11,1,1, 10, 1,2, 5],
    "col3": [5, 6,7,8, 9, 1,2, 5]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dic)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.day)
df = df.drop(['day'], axis=1)
df.insert(0, 'day_name', df.index.weekday_name)
```

Result:

```
            day_name  data  col2  col3
day                                   
2019-01-18    Friday     0    10     5
2019-01-18    Friday     1    11     6
2019-01-18    Friday     3     1     7
2019-01-19  Saturday     3     1     8
2019-01-19  Saturday     0    10     9
2019-01-25    Friday     1     1     1
2019-02-19   Tuesday     2     2     2
2019-02-24    Sunday     5     5     5
```

Now i need to group this data by week and by max value from column 2. I done this by:

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.to_period("w")).agg({'col2':'max'})
```

Result:

```
                       col2
day                        
2019-01-14/2019-01-20    11
2019-01-21/2019-01-27     1
2019-02-18/2019-02-24     5
```

Question:
How to get day date on witch the max grouped value is occurred?

Expected result:

```
                       col2 day
day                        
2019-01-14/2019-01-20    11 2019-01-18
2019-01-21/2019-01-27     1 2019-01-25 
2019-02-18/2019-02-24     5 2019-02-24
```

Thanks for Your time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with changed [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) - specify column name after `groupby` and pass tuples:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.index.to_period("w"))['col2'].agg([('col2','max'), ('day','idxmax')])
print (df1)
                       col2        day
day                                   
2019-01-14/2019-01-20    11 2019-01-18
2019-01-21/2019-01-27     1 2019-01-25
2019-02-18/2019-02-24     5 2019-02-24
```

Pandas 0.25+ solution:

```
df.groupby(df.index.to_period("w")).agg(col2=pd.NamedAgg(column='col2', aggfunc='max'),
                                        day=pd.NamedAgg(column='col2', aggfunc='idxmax'))
```

Comment: Thank You. Now i know that i can pass idx to agg :)